# Javascript redirect based on option value selected issue

Tags: javascript

I have following HTML code:

```
<select class="fly" id="size">
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="M">M</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="item_add" id="BuyButton">Buy</a>
```

And following JS:

```
var s = document.getElementById("size");
var strSize = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;


document.getElementById("BuyButton").onclick = function () {
location.href = "../add_to_cart.php?product=<?php echo $id; ?>&size=" +strSize;
};
```

When someone click on Buy button I want to redirect him on add_to_cart.php file with id and size parameters. ID is ok, but with JS based parameter SIZE there is a problem, because no matter what is selected in the SELECT form, it always gets the first value. In this case it's "S" value. Where's the problem? Thank you.

Comment: For one, add a "select size" with an empty value and test the value is no empty when running the script - then move the `strSize = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;`
 to inside the click and then cancel the click or use a button type="button" instead of a link

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Comment: `document.getElementById("BuyButton").addEventListener("click",function (e) {
e.preventdefault();
var s = document.getElementById("size");
var strSize = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
if (strSize) window.location= "../add_to_cart.php?product=<?php echo $id; ?>&size=" +strSize;
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put everything inside the function, otherwise it will only take the selected option when the page loads.

```
document.getElementById("BuyButton").onclick = function () {
   var s = document.getElementById("size");
   var strSize = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
   location.href = "../add_to_cart.php?product=<?php echo $id; ?>&size=" + strSize;
};
```